# How to configure Two different contexts work together(DbContext and IdentityDbContext)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I’m going to make a new project and I have some problem to with design of my project. I want to have two standalone databases - DbContext and IdentityDbContext but I want It work together, DbContext models should have a foreign keys to IdentityUser! For example, I have an Order model in my DbContext and user made order. So I should save which user created the order with a foreign key or there is any other way to do it?

Comment: i think its not possible to add foreign key to deference database

Comment: @LittleDragon I understand this but how to make them work together?